# Computing subgradients, a basic example.

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

> A vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a *subgradient* of a convex function at $x$ if $$f(y) \geq f(x) + <v, y - x>$$ for all $y \in dom(f).$
>
> The set of all sub gradients is known as the *sub differential* denoted by $\partial f (x)$

Here is the example which I am stuck with

> Let $f(x) = max \{0, (x^2 - 1)/2 \}$, then $\partial f(1) = [0,1]$ and $\partial f(-1) = [-1, 0]$

I am aware that the functions inside the max function is convex, so there is better way to do this. But the method I am using, from first principles, is not leading me to the right answer.

Note

$$f(y) = \max \{ 0, (y^2 - 1)/2 \} \geq f(1) + v(y - 1) = 0 + v(y - 1)$$

Case I. Letting $0  > (y^2 - 1)/2 \iff y \in (-1, 1)$.

Case II. Letting $0 < (y^2 - 1)/2 \iff y \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (1, \infty)$

Employing case I yields the inequality

$$0 \geq v(y - 1)$$. As $y \in (-1,1)$, RHS is true for every $v \in [0, \infty)$.

Employing case II yields the inequality

$$(y^2 - 1)/2\geq v(y - 1) \implies y + 1 \geq 2v$$. As $y \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (1, \infty)$, There appears to be no unique answer for $v$ depending on the value of $y$. But we may actually throw out this case since $y \notin dom(f)$.

Comment: You can just visualize the graph of $f$, and visualize the graphs of the affine minorants of $f$ which are exact at $x = 1$ or at $x = -1$.  For example, at $x = 1$, you can see there's an affine minorant of slope $1/2$ which is exact.

Comment: May I get an analytic result, at least to point out my mistakes? I can't draw very well

Comment: I am also not familiar with the term  "affine minor ant"

Comment: "Affine minorant" might be a bad term because it sounds way more fancy than it really is.  Here's a [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+max%280%2C+%28x%5E2+-+1%29%2F2%29+%3B+y+%3D+.5*%28x+-+1%29) on Wolfram Alpha that explains why $1/2$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $x = 1$.  Visualizing like this, you can see that $\partial f(1) = [0,1]$.

Comment: And without a graph, how could I achieve this…? From first principles espcially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight error when you conclude that $y + 1 \geq 2v$ for all $y \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (1,\infty)$.  That inequality is only valid for $y \in (1,\infty)$.

If $y \in (\infty, -1)$, then $y -1$ is negative.  So when you divide through by $y-1$, you have divided by a negative number, and the direction of the inequality must change.

Being careful about this point, we conclude that
\begin{equation}
y + 1 \geq 2v \quad \text{for all } y \in (1,\infty)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y + 1 \leq 2v \quad \text{for all } y \in (-\infty,-1).
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Condition (1) is equivalent to $v \leq 1$, and condition (2) is equivalent to $v \geq 0$.
So (1) and (2) are satisfied when $v \in [0,1]$.

For this problem, the answer can be obtained easily just by visualizing the graph of $f$, as in this [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+max%280%2C+%28x%5E2+-+1%29%2F2%29+%3B+y+%3D+.5%2A%28x+-+1%29).

Comment: I see I made a dumb mistake. I reckon we also take the condition of case I into account? The intersection of all three cases?

Comment: Yeah that's right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formular (see on page 4 of https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf)
$$
\partial f(x)=\text{co}\left(\bigcup\left\{\partial f_i(x):f_i(x)=f(x)\right\}\right),
$$
where $f(x)=\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}$.

Since $f_1(x)=0, f_2(x)==(x^2-1)/2$, we have
$$
\partial f_1(x)=\{0\}, \quad \partial f_2(x)=\{x\}
$$
For $x=1$ we have $f(1)=\max\{f_1(1),f_2(1)\}=\max\{0,0\}=0$. Hence
$$
\partial f(1)=\text{co}\left(\partial f_1(1)\bigcup\partial f_2(1)\right)=[0,1].
$$
For $x=-1$ we have $f(-1)=\max\{f_1(-1),f_2(-1)\}=\max\{0,0\}=0$. Hence
$$
\partial f(-1)=\text{co}\left(\partial f_1(-1)\bigcup\partial f_2(-1)\right)=[-1,0].
$$